# I am using a regex snippet query string path

Tags: javascript

Using the following to load images base on two ids one is the and bookid and the out is the client. My folder structures is this.

`root path = flipbooks`

The subfolders under flipbooks are books and clients. In the subfolder books I have a .NET page titled tablet. The tablet code behind checks the bookid of client and renders  the tablet page with images in a flipbook fashion.

Because we have over 15000 records and flipbooks already created and stored in the database, I don't move the client folder under the books subfolders. I need the code below to get to the client subfolder in the query string and help to change this would be helpful.

The result now is: `http://www.somewebsite.com/books/client/images/someimage1.jpg[^]`
I need the results to be:  `http://www.somewebsite.com/client/images/someimage1.jpg[^]`.

I tried moving the tablet.aspx file to the root flipbooks and it works but i have provide a user name and password each time. This need to be access by the public and my root is protected. Don't want to have to change permission.

I am trying to remove the /books

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
var results = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
 return results ?
    decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '))
    : null;
```

}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem rewrote the c# code. to just query the Request string and replace the books/client with just clients.